Receiving -80 dBm on HF
When using my EFHW antenna, I saw that it was -80dBm to -90dBm. So, I can barely make out anything they are saying. I read that you are supposed to have the antenna running north to south, and the lowest point should be half a wavelength above ground. I did all those things, but I am still receiving -80dBm. Should I make the antenna higher? One end is sticking out of a window and I hung the other end up a tree (what else am I supposed to use?) Or am I wrong and it is supposed to go east to west? Yes, I have low SNR. I am using a coax for the feedline. How do you add a counterpoise? I'm using a SWR meter and trimming the antenna until I reach 1:1. The feedline is surprisingly skinny, is that one of the contributors to the problem? Here is the link to it. It's something like ~3 mm? I want to know why I am having poor reception so I can fix it.

is low power the problem, or low SNR? If it's just low power, adding an LNA would solve the issue.

Check your antenna matching transformer. Orientation and height will make a small difference but not many dB.
I happen to have measured my end-fed antenna this week... The noise level was higher than that, maybe -70 dBm across the band. Medium wave stations were over -30 dBm.
Mine is 20 metres long, with a home-made transformer. I tested both the transformer and then antenna carefully.
One possible data point is that some cheap Amazon baluns are wound or connected incorrectly and just don't do what they claim. (Sample of two). The 49:1 unun is more difficult to get right.
If you don't already have one, get a NanoVNA and test everything step by step.

The direction should not make all the signals low level.  Running out the window and up a tree is a common arrangement and you should receive plenty of signals.
At this point, we need to know more.  What radio are you using?  What frequency are you listening to?
If you can just barely hear the voices it makes me think it is more likely that you have a feedline or radio problem than an antenna problem pre se.
More info please!
